# Optimize nested for loops in Matlab using Vectorization

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, lookup-tables

I am a newbie to Matlab and I am currently trying to optimize a nested for loop as below. The loop is currently running forever for my input.

```
for i = 1:size(mat,1)
    for j = 1:size(mat,2)
          mat(i,j) = some_mapping(mat(i,j)+1);
    end
end
```

However I can't find a way to vectorize it. I have tried bsxfun and arrayfun but it does not seem to work (or even run more slowly than the loop).

Maybe I was doing it in a wrong way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not `mat = some_mapping(mat+1)`?

Comment: what does `some_mapping` do?

Comment: @AndrasDeak  I guess I can't do it that way. some_mapping is a 1x256 double. So the operation itself is not vectorized.

Comment: @Shai some_mapping is a 1x256 double vector. Something like a loop-up table (in Java-like languages...)

Comment: Have you tried `some_mapping(mat+1)`? if it's a simple lookup table, then there's no reason why it won't work. Make sure `mat` values are between 0 and `numel(some_mapping)-1`.

Comment: @Shai i just tried `mat2= some_mapping(mat+1)`. However when I output `isequal(mat, mat2)` I get 0, which means they are not equal. I don't know what can be the problem... Here the some_mapping does not have the same dimension as mat, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok I think i get your idea...so I tried your suggestion but I found the results are not equal (as posted in my previous comment).

Comment: of course `mat` and `mat2` are not equal. `mat2` is the result of applying LUT on `mat`. Unless your mapping is the identity mapping `mat` and `mat2` will never be identical.

Comment: @Shai yes I found the cause...I was carelessly using the updated mat again in comparison. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704461/optimize-nested-for-loops-in-matlab-using-vectorization/34705071#comment57154850_34704461), if `some_mapping` is simply a look-up-table operation, then

```
mat = some_mapping( mat+1 );
```

*Notes:*
 - In order of the mapping to work, the values of `mat` must be integers in the range `[0..numel(some_mapping)-1]`.
 - The `size` of `some_mapping` does not affect the `size` of the result, it will be identical in `size` to `mat`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak. (a) thanks for spotting my typo. (b) both vectorized and nested loops version of the code will fail, but I suppose it would be easier to debug the nested version - as it will be very clear what entry *exactly* caused the error.